# No terminal in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

An error will popup whenever I launch JupyterLab:

```
[W 17:36:55.292 LabApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'winpty.cywinpty')
```

Hence, I don't have terminal in JupyterLab. And I installed pywinpty in Python. I looked everywhere and there isn't any solution for this problem. Anybody met this problem or knows how to solve this problem?